# Xpath Case insensitive expression to get attributes from an XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Cunrrently im reading some `XML` files and extracting some values using some predefined paths with the Help of `Xpath`

The paths look like this:

```
Comprobante/@Fecha
```

the path above for example would be used to extract the attribute `@Fecha`, the file looks something like this:

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" Fecha="2017-10-25T19:13:19">
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Here´s an example of the code im using to get the data, in this case I will be getting the value of the attribue `@Fecha`.

**Code Example**

```
 File inputFile = new File(file);
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
 dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();                     
 Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
 XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();                     
 XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("Comprobante/@Fecha")
 String names = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

As far as I know XML files are case sensitive, the files I have been reading always had `@Fecha` with the letter `F` in caps, but recently I received a lot of files with `@fecha` instead of `@Fecha` in addition to the usual files with `@Fecha`, I can´t control how the files are written at the moment so I need to find a workaround for this problem because the code I have returns `null` when applied to the files that have `@fecha`

**Example of a file with `@fecha` :**

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" fecha="2017-10-25T19:13:19">
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

I could do an `if` statement and check if the value Im getting is `empty` and then check again but with `@fecha` instead of `@Fecha` , like so:

```
 File inputFile = new File(file);
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
 dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();                     
 Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
 XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();                     
 XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("Comprobante/@Fecha")
 String names = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

 if(names.isEmpty()){
     XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("Comprobante/@fecha")
     String names = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
 }
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to do this with a `Xpath Expression` that gets the value of `@Fecha` regardless of the size of letter `F`,instead of the `IF` expression, I found that I can do it using the function `translate`, something like:

```
translate(@Fecha, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

But I cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath,

```
translate(@Fecha, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

translates the `@Fecha` attribute *value* to lower case.

This **XPath 1.0**,

```
Comprobante/@*[translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                       'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
               = 'fecha']
```

selects the attribute of `Comprobante` whose *name* in lower-case is `fecha`.

Or more concisely in **XPath 2.0:**

```
Comprobante/@*[lower-case(local-name()) = 'fecha']
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly, the XPath 2.0 expression didn't work I guess is because im not using Xpath 2.0, how can I can i know what version of XPath im using ?  I just added the imports for Xpath with the help of Netbeans IDE, like so: `import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;`

Comment: There is no standard XPath call that will reveal the version. 
 You just have to try a XPath 2.0 function such as `current-date()` and see if it works, or know what the library supports.   `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` is XPath 1.0.